# Do I need to change any settings or turn things on or off before installing Ubuntu 18.04.02?

Tags: system-installation

I have been testing 18.04.2 for several days via live session. It seems that all things work ok. Programs run, devices work, music, videos, DVDs, and music plays (after installing codecs etc.). So it seems I'm ready to go. However, I am hesitant as I have read about issues with installing over Windows 10. I have read many questions and looked into the wiki but am still somewhat confused as what to do. I have previously installed earlier versions of Ubuntu (12.04, 16.04) on a netbook (Win 7), and a Dell desktop (Vista) with no issues. In both cases I just installed Ubuntu and erased previous OSes.
At present I want to install over Win 10 on a Dell Inspiron 15 Laptop with an Intel Core 13 7100U Processor, 6 gig ram, 1T harddrive. Some of the things I have read say to disable quick boot, disable Intel Smart Response Technology, and set BIOS to boot in UEFI mode. Some of this info may be dated so I'm not sure if it applies to my situation now.
So my question is, do I need to change any settings before installing, or will I be ok just installing from live session and choosing the automaic install method that overwrites the existing OS. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I do not want to end up with a bricked box.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you keep Windows 10 installed, as you may need it to run apps that don't run on Ubuntu, or if you have to do things like BIOS/firmware updates, etc. Create a dual-boot environment so you can boot to either OS. I would turn off display blanking, suspend, or sleep mode, during the update.

Comment: I have considered the BIOS issue and wondered if I could update that. I notice when I press F12 to boot the USB for a live session, there is a choice to flash the BIOS and I wondered whether I would be able to update it via that method.

Comment: Yes, some BIOS's allow self-updating. I'd manually enter the BIOS, get the version, then go to the manufacturor's web site and check for a newer BIOS. Instructions should be there also.